# Extract html dependencies for .Rmd file (containing htmlwidgets)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

### Question

How could I create a function which would take a .Rmd file (containing htmlwidgets code) as its input, and output a html file containing its JavaScript/CSS dependencies?

Specifically, the tempfile rmarkdown generates for pandoc's `--include-in-header` argument, when rendering to html.

### Details

Example -- myfile.Rmd:

````
This is some text

```{r}
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(nhtemp, main = "New Haven Temperatures")
```
````

Running `rmarkdown::render('myfile.Rmd')` passes a tempfile to the `--include-in-header` pandoc argument, containing all the JavaScript and CSS needed to render the interactive graphic (either compressed data:uri format, or html links to copied files). This is included in the final html file, so that everything renders in the browser. It's this tempfile I'd like to be able to generate.

It's appears to be output by passing a dependencies object to the internal function `rmarkdown:::html_dependencies_as_string`. I'd like to be able to generate this file for arbitrary .Rmd documents containing htmlwidgets code.

### Context

I'm interested in blogging using knitr and Jekyll, as Yihui outlines [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll). However, the disadvantage of this approach is that none of the htmlwidgets functionality works, because the [dependency injection step is missed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll/issues/8). This is because pandoc is called by Ruby/Jekyll, and so does not benefit from htmlwidgets/rmarkdown's invisible magic. I'd like to add a function to my build process which writes the dependencies to a html file, which can be included in the html header by Jeykll if required.

Comment: this might help also http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2016/8/4/htmlwidgets-look-ma-no-r

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible solution http://benjcunningham.org/2016/06/13/hacking-together-htmlwidgets-for-jekyll.html, that refers to an older post that also offers a solution: https://brendanrocks.com/htmlwidgets-knitr-jekyll/.

A bit hacky. An official solution to this problems is still pending. There is an open issue in yihui/knitr-jekyll: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-jekyll/issues/8

Comment: Please could you nevertheless explain the solution in addition to the links you just gave ?